# Is it possible to compile/serve only a subset of assets? How?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

For a certain controller/action, I would like to serve only a specific subset of CSS assets. Is such a thing possible?

I want something like this in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<% if newsletter_show? %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "foo", "bar", "baz" %>
<% else %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<% end %>
```

Note: when the condition is true, not only do I serve specific css files (*foo*, *bar*, and *baz*), I also purposely don't serve javascript.

This works perfectly in *development*, but in *production* it fails because apparently we can't have disjoint stylesheets, since they're precompiled as a whole. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1** :
If you add foo bar and baz to precompiles, it should work :

In config/application.rb :

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(foo.css bar.css baz.css)
```

**Option 2** :
You could also create another css grouped file :

In app/assets/stylesheets/newsletter.css :

```
/*
*= require foo
*= require bar
*= require baz
*/
```

In config/application.rb :

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(newsletter.css)
```

In the view :

```
<% if newsletter_show? %>    
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'newsletter' %>
#...
```

Don't forget to recompile the assets :)

Comment: Thank you kindly! I used option 2.